# How can I modify environments on beamer without knowing their original definition

Tags: beamer, environments

My question is similar to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565988/making-a-small-modification-to-a-latex-environment). I've also tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56988/change-only-the-ending-with-renewenvironment), but didn't work for me.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{frame}\justifying
    \lipsum[11]
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\columnwidth}
            \begin{itemize}\justifying
                \item \lipsum[11]
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\columnwidth}\justifying
            \lipsum[11]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to modify the `frame`, `itemize` and `column` environments to append the `\justifying` command to they.

I don't want to create new environments.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: `\xapptocmd` from `xpatch` package but you should really know what you do here. I don't recommend it applying it without knowing the definition

Comment: @ChristianHupfer your sugestion works well for `frame` and `itemize`, but not for `column`, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, since `column` has an argument (or even an optional argument) and here the `\xapptocmd` breaks -- you've to know how it's defined

Comment: Why do you want to do it without knowing their definitions particularly? If I give you a package which makes the changes, will that do if you don't have to read the source of my package? (I.e. you can choose ignorance.)

Comment: @paulequilibrio: See my undeleted answer as another suggestion

Comment: @cfr just for simplicity. Nothing at all against reading the sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\xapptocmd` appends code to other commands (under certain circumstances), as well as to the environment starter commands `\frame` etc.

However, in order to make this code really working, it's better to know how the definitions are. `\xapptocmd` works for `\begin{frame}`, but not for `\begin{frame}[options]{Foo}` etc. and it does not work for `\begin{column}` due to the optional arguments.

In order to grab this, I've decided to use `xparse` and `\RenewDocumentEnvironment`, injecting `\justifying`
or use `\AtBeginEnvironment` from `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\xapptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}
\xapptocmd{\itemize}{\justifying}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}} % Useful???

\LetLtxMacro\origcolumn\column
\LetLtxMacro\origcolumnend\endcolumn

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{column}{O{}g}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \origcolumn[#1]{#2}%
  }{%
    \origcolumn[#1]%
  }%    
  \justifying%
}{%
  \origcolumnend%
}


\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{frame}%\justifying
    \lipsum[11]
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\columnwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
            \item \lipsum[11]
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\columnwidth}
            \lipsum[11]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which defines a Lua function that serves to append `\justifying` to all instances of `\begin{frame}`, `\begin{itemize}`, and `\begin{column}{...}`, where `...` is arbitrary (but probably something like `0.5\textwidth`). The function is run by the `process_input_buffer` callback, which operates at a very early stage of processing, specifically, *before* any "ordinary" processing by TeX takes place.

An advantage of this approach is that the environments `frame`, `itemize`, and `column` are not actually modified in any way. Thus, it's also not necessary to know how these environments are defined in the first place.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for "\justifying" macro
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function add_justifying ( line )
   line = string.gsub ( line, "\\begin{frame}",      "%0\\justifying" )
   line = string.gsub ( line, "\\begin{itemize}",    "%0\\justifying" )
   line = string.gsub ( line, "\\begin{column}{.-}", "%0\\justifying" )
   return line
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , add_justifying, "add_justifying" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{frame}
    \lipsum[11]
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\columnwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item \lipsum[11]
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\columnwidth}
            \lipsum[11]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right: I just overlooked the \justifying there. It would probably not work for \begin{frame}{foo} etc. without really using \renewcommand and \LetLtxMacro

Comment: @Mico your answer works well, but I prefer don't use `lualatex`. Any other sugestion?

Comment: @paulequilibrio - I'm afraid I don't have another suggestion. Incidentally, why do you prefer not to use `lualatex`?

Comment: Because this is part of a shared work that is already too complicated and I wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: @paulequilibrio - I'm also in favor of keeping things as simple as possible. :-) Lua(La)TeX may indeed still seem new -- and maybe even foreboding -- to some. However, as LuaTeX is a superset of pdfTeX, virtually all tex files that compile correctly under pdfLaTeX will compile equally well under LuaLaTeX -- subject to a few, very minor tweaks. For sure, if your co-authors happen to use, for instance, badly out of date TeX distributions and if they can't be bothered to upgrade to the latest version, asking them to switch from pdflatex to lualatex may involve more effort than they can handle...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Was your comment meant to be attached to this answer?

Comment: @Mico: No, to my answer, but I've deleted it in the meantime, shifted the comment to your answer and edited my answer. I feared already that `\xapptocmd` would not work for all environments there

Answer (score 5):

If your purpose is to have everything justified, redefine `\raggedright` to do nothing, keeping a copy of it just in case of need.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\latexraggedright\raggedright % just in case
\let\raggedright\relax
\justifying % because beamer.cls issues \raggedright

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{frame}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\columnwidth}

\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[11]
\end{itemize}

\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\columnwidth}
\lipsum[11]
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't find it a good idea, personally.