# Beamer: how to justify the whole text?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, text

How can I justify the text in the whole document in beamer without using `\usepackage{ragged2e}` and `\justifying` at the beginning of each frame?

```
\documentclass[8pt,handout,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont} %used inside itemize environment \item[\ding{226}]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]

\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-1x1}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{226}] \lipsum[2]
\item[\ding{226}] \lipsum[3]
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \lipsum[3]
 \begin{itemize}
   \item[\ding{226}] \lipsum[4]
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\lipsum[5]
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: I had already checked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55589/text-justify-in-beamer) out but it does not work for both the `columns` and the `itemize` environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text justify in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55589/text-justify-in-beamer)

Comment: @Benjamin This alone is not enough to deal with the itemization, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/justify-text-inside-itemize-environment-with-beamer-class. And columns are also a problem.

Comment: So I think, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271330/7883 works.

Comment: A very gross, crude way of getting that could be to redifine the `\raggedright` command: `\newcommand{\oldraggedright}{\raggedright}    \renewcommand{\raggedright}{\justifying}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To patch "normal" frames, the solution can be found [text justify in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55589/text-justify-in-beamer)

---

Itemize has also already a solution on this side: [Justify text inside itemize environment with beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/justify-text-inside-itemize-environment-with-beamer-class)

---

But I could not find one to automatically justify the contents of columns. So I tried a bit, failed in the attempt to patch `\begin{column}...`, but with `\column` it works as following:

```
\documentclass[8pt,handout,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont} %used inside itemize environment \item[\ding{226}]
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\apptocmd{\column}{}{\justifying}{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
    {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
    {\def\makelabel##1{%
            {%
                \hss\llap{{%
                        \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    \fi%
    \beamer@cramped%
    \justifying% NEW
    %\raggedright% ORIGINAL
    \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}

\renewcommand<>\beamer@columncom[2][\beamer@colmode]{%
    \beamer@colclose%
    \def\beamer@colclose{\end{minipage}\hfill\end{actionenv}\ignorespaces}%
\begin{actionenv}#3%
    \setkeys{beamer@col}{#1}%
    \begin{minipage}[\beamer@colalign]{#2}%
        \leavevmode%
        %\raggedright
            \justifying% NEW
        \beamer@colheadskip\ignorespaces}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]

\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-1x1}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{226}] \lipsum[2]
\item[\ding{226}] \lipsum[3]
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \lipsum[3]
 \begin{itemize}
   \item[\ding{226}] \lipsum[4]
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[t]
\column{0.4\textwidth}{
\lipsum[3]
}
\column{0.4\textwidth}{
\lipsum[5]
}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as `itemize` is concerned, I have two issues: I would like to use `\usepackage{enumitem}` and `\setlist{leftmargin=2.2mm}` to indent the items: the problem is that I get an error. The second issue is that, when I have an `itemize`  environment inside another, the font size decreases. Is there a way to maintain the font size the same?