# Hyphenation in beamerposter

Tags: beamer, hyphenation, beamerposter

I am preparing a poster presentation and due to historical reasons I am using beamerposter class for this. At some point I realized that the hyphenation in beamer is "switched off" because authors of the package *know* that there should be no hyphenation in the presentation. 
However, for the **poster** presentation, missing hyphenation looks ugly.

What is the correct way to use hyphenation with beamerposter? The solution from [Hyphenation in Beamer Presentations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44556/hyphenation-in-beamer-presentations#44669) works, but needs some extra work by fitting the formatting to other parts of the presentation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[final,xcolor={cmyk}]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} 
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % justify text

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.49\linewidth}
\begin{block}{Deafault Beamer behavior}
\kant[1-2]
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Hyphenation works here}\justifying\leftskip=4ex\rightskip=4ex
\kant[1-2]
\end{block}

\end{column}
\begin{column}{.49\linewidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that to make them look similar I need to change leftskip and rightskip to correct value which depends on the theme.

Comment: Can you give us some MWE to start playing with?

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291316/36296 could be of help