# Justify content in beamer blocks

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, block

I have a beamer presentation that contains different blocks, I need to justify all my paragraphs (right and left) how can I do that?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \begin{block}{}
         content that i want to justify
    \end{block}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271330/7883 may be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\addtobeamertemplate` to add the `\justifying` command from the `ragged2e` package to the beginning of the `block` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % For \justifying command
\usepackage{lipsum} % Only for demo text

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying} % Justify all blocks

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \begin{block}{}
         \lipsum[12]
    \end{block}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Justified output]

Comment: thank you, it works but only for simple phrases and not on lists phrases

Comment: @HindDev What do you mean? What are "lists phrases"?

Comment: I mean items on an enumeration or itemize

Comment: That is another problem, with an answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50019/30280).