# Justify text in alert blocks

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, block

how can I justify the text inside an alert block?

```
\begin{frame} 
\begin{alertblock}{hello} 
text to justify
\end{alertblock} 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Inside one `alertblock` or inside all of them?

Comment: @campa inside them all please

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the answer from [Justify content in beamer blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298639/82917) you can redefine the `block alerted begin` beamer template

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% for dummy text
\usepackage{ragged2e}% for \justifying
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{}{\justifying}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{block}
\lipsum[66]
\end{block}

\begin{alertblock}{alertblock}
\lipsum[66]
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]